# docker-compose not sending signals to trap

Tags: docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  port-forwarder:
    image: test
    container_name: port-forwarder
    volumes:
      - "/path_to_scripts/port_forwarder.sh:/port_forwarder.sh"
    command: "/port_forwarder.sh"
```

port_forwarder.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trap 'echo exiting ; exit 0' SIGTERM TERM SIGINT INT EXIT WINCH SIGWINCH
tail -f /dev/null
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.12.0
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

If I build the image and run it using

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --name test -it --rm -v /path_to_scripts/port_forwarder.sh:/port_forwarder.sh test /port_forwarder.sh
```

and then hit ctrl-c, it catches the SIGTERM and writes "exiting" on the console. But when I run it using 'docker-compose up' and hit ctrl-c it hangs and is killed after 10 seconds. I am using docker on OSX. What could be the reason and how can I catch the termination signal from docker-compose?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same problem. You however are using the command which might wrap it in a shell script when executing, however mine doesn't do that.